# After returning an ActionResult of ContentType PDF, Microsoft Edge logs out the user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-edge

When a user clicks on a print preview button, a PDF preview page is rendered using this class inheriting `ActionResult`

```
public class PDFResult : System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult
{
    private readonly byte[] pdf;

    public PDFResult(byte[] pdf)
    {
        this.pdf = pdf;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.IsClientConnected)
        {

            var response = context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ContentType = DocumentTypes.PDF.MimeType;
            response.BinaryWrite(pdf);
            response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

The preview page renders correctly and opens in a separate tab. However, making any other request on the page afterwards will cause a redirect to the SignIn page for the user. So instead of making a request like `SomeObject?object?Id=SomeGuid` with result 200, the result will be 302.

This issue is ***unique to Microsoft Edge***. Additionally, this does not happen on localhost, so I cannot debug through it.

Comment: When you say "making any other request on the page", you mean the page with the PDF preview or the original request?  Do you have any Authorize/Anonymous decorators on the controller(s) that host this action?  Lastly, do you have a setting in Edge that may clear browsing data on popup or leaving site?

Comment: Redirect happens on the page from which original request was made.  There are no Authorize/Anonymous decorators on any methods that host this action. No such settings on Edge either -- this has been tested to be an issue on multiple machines.

Comment: We've encountered compatibility issues with our web apps and IE products.  It's possible there's some sort of header that Edge might need...I'll do some research.

Comment: Have you checked dev tools in Edge to see what headers are present and if any are rejected/ignored?  Can you view cookies as well and maybe compare to other browsers that work as expected?

Comment: Thanks for reaching out again -- I did compare headers along with cookies and unfortunately they are the same for both browsers.